# Why i get result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE); == INACTIVE?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I work with camera2API on `Samsung S5` and if i try get state of focus i get value `0` which is equals to `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE`...

There is snip of code :

```
private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case CameraHelper.STATE_PREVIEW: {
                // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.

here i get ---> Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);

                if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START == afState) {
                    if (areWeFocused) {
                        Log.e("---!!! HERE !!!--- :", String.valueOf(areWeFocused));
                    }else {
                    }
                }

                if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED == afState) {
                    areWeFocused = true;
                } else {
                    areWeFocused = false;
                }

                break;
            }
```

But i also tried to test it on my `Meizu MX5` and i get `1` - `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START` or `2` - `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED`

Question is : what is the difference in my code? Why do i get `0` in one case and `1 or 2` in another?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Donato really I don't remember...

Comment: I getting it on emulator, on my device work fine, any reason found?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but i just ran into the same issue. Read through the Android docs about ControlAfState (AF = Auto Focus for those who are unaware, like I was). If AutoFocus Mode (afMode) is set to AF_MODE_OFF you will get the ControlAfState of Inactive.

[Android CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_STATE)